# How to merge a git repo into a parent repo maintaining commit history?

Tags: git, parent-child, git-merge, repo, git-history

I have always kept track of files in the `child` repo. But now I also need to keep track of another `child`, so I renamed them to `child1` and `child2`. I would like to maintain only a `parent` directory that contains both folders, but I don't want to lose commits from the `child` repo.

Before:

```sh
/
/docs/
/docs/child/
/docs/child/.git/           # repo at child level
/docs/child/file-a
/docs/child/file-b
```

After:

```sh
/
/docs/
/docs/parent/
/docs/parent/.git/          # parent repo contains all files and child1 commits
/docs/parent/child1/
/docs/parent/child1/file-a
/docs/parent/child1/file-b
/docs/parent/child2/
/docs/parent/child2/file-c
```

How can achieve this simple setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a Git repository contains *commits*, not files.  (The commits then contain files, but we work commit-by-commit, not file-by-file.)

Your existing repository, which you had stored in `docs/child` (as the `.git` directory therein), contains a series of commits.  Each commit has a full snapshot of every file.<sup>1</sup>  The files in these commits are `file-a` and `file-b`, for instance.

You would now like this same repository to add *new* commits in which files in the commits are named `child1/file-a`, `child1/file-b`, and `child2/file-c` for instance.  That's easy to do: enter the repository working tree, create `child1` and `child2` sub-directories, and—**for convenience**<sup>2</sup>—use `git mv` to rename `file-a` to the name `child1/file-a` and rename `file-b` to `child1/file-b`.  Create new file `child2/file-c`, use `git add` on it, and run `git commit`, and you add one new commit to the existing repository; in this one new commit, the contents are stored under these new names, while in all the existing commits, the snapshots store the files under their old names.

Note that Git does not store directories: it just stores *files* whose names may or may not contain embedded (forward) slashes.  Git will, on demand as needed, *create* a directory that your OS requires, because your OS insists that there's no such thing as a file named `child1/file-a`: that this is a directory named `child1` holding a file named `file-a`.  Git insists that, no, this is a file named `child1/file-a`; Git fully manages<sup>3</sup> this mismatch between Git's idea of files and your OS's.

Remember: **a Git repository holds commits.**  Git isn't about files or branches, but rather about commits.  The commits hold files (which we need to get our work done), and the branch names help us (and Git) find the commits we want that contain the files we need.  But at the repository level, Git is about *commits*.  When you think about things stored in a Git repository, think about the commits.  Each one holds a *snapshot of all files*, plus some metadata.

---

<sup>1</sup>The files inside commits are compressed and Git-ified so that only Git can read them, and literally nothing at all can write them.  They are *de-duplicated* as well (within and across commits) so the fact that every commit saves every file every time doesn't cause the repository to bloat to ridiculous sizes (though some binary files defeat this trick, and then the repository *does* bloat to ridiculous sizes, which is why it's unwise to store large binary files in Git).

<sup>2</sup>As far as Git is concerned, there's no difference between removing some file named `file-a` and creating a totally new `child1/file-a` file that holds the same contents, vs renaming an existing `file-a` to `child1/file-a`.  The final *commits* simply hold the contents; if the contents of `child1/file-a` in the new commit match, byte-for-byte, the contents of `file-a` in the old commit, they're de-duplicated.  Still, it's a heck of a lot more convenient to use `git mv` here, unless you've already used plain `mv` or whatever renaming or restructuring commands your OS uses.  If so, feel free to use `git rm` and/or `git add` to update Git's idea of the files' names and contents.  Git won't care how you got from the old setup to the new setup: all it contains are *commits*, and those commits just hold snapshots of files (plus metadata, but the metadata do not contain renaming information).

<sup>3</sup>For some value of "fully" anyway: the directory/file conflict code in Git has a history of the occasional small bug-ette.  It's pretty good, all in all, considering how complicated this mismatch is, between Git's way of thinking and the OS's.  Still, in some cases of complicated detected-after-the-fact renames across commits that result in files moving to new directories, some versions of Git are better than others.

Answer (score 0):

Based on torek answer, since I did not need to merge two child repos into a parent one, I ended up re-using the initial `child` repo as parent. What I did was:

```sh
# enter the child repo
cd child
# create the new child folder
mkdir child1
# move all files inside "child" from their original location to their multi-child destination
# the -k flag avoids the error caused by copying child1 into child1
# this operation doesn't copy files or folders starting with a dot
git mv -k * ./child1
# running `git add -A && git status` would show that all files have been renamed (moved)
# create child2 and move files there
mkdir child2
```

Now the structure looks like this:

```sh
/
/docs/
/docs/child/
/docs/child/.git/
/docs/child/child1/
/docs/child/child1/file-a
/docs/child/child1/file-b
/docs/child/child2/
/docs/child/child2/file-c
```

Now one can rename the "child" folder into "parent" and run `git config -e` inside it to point to another remote repo, if needed.